# Honda Accord trunk latch button won't open the trunk

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, trunk, latch

The issue is regarding a Honda Accord Euro 2007 model (CL7), The button on the trunk lid won't open it anymore.

- The trunk can be opened using the key fob, so the electrical actuator is in working order.
- Tested using a multimeter, the switch on the trunk lid closes the circuit, so that is in working order.
- The trunk can be opened using the release tab inside the car, but that opens it mechanically by wire, so it's irrelevant.

Where can the issue be?

Answer (score 2):

The button on the lid isn't working, or there's a problem with the switch wiring. Your testing has been pretty thorough, you know that the actuator works, that really doesn't leave any other options.

You will need to get at the switch and wiring and do some testing, replacing the switch if necessary.

EDIT: It sounds like the switch has been tested as working, the problem is likely the wiring. Wires themselves rarely go bad, it's the connections that are usually at fault. This can be because of corrosion, or vibration. Try disconnecting the harnesses at both ends and cleaning the contacts. Use your continuity tester to make sure the end to end of each wire and connector works.

Comment: But the button seems to be working. It closes the electric circuit when being pressed.

Comment: Where are you testing that from? Are you testing at the button itself? If so the problem is the wiring between the button and the actuator.

Comment: Yes, the testing was done on the button itself. I was thinking that the wiring could be the culprit, but why would it just go bad all of a sudden?

Comment: Okay, on the off chance that someone may have the same issue in the future, there is a _switch_ in the trunk, underneath the rear windshield that has the sole purpose of deactivating the button.

Comment: Haha, who would have thought? Write it up as an answer @ConstantinDumitrașcu, it's okay to answer your own question if you've done the work to find it.